# partition range other than one day is not supported sql server

Tags: sql-server

I got below error.

> partition range other than one day is not supported sql server

When I checked the partition scheme and function then today's date (2020-02-29 leap year) is not there in the definition of partition scheme\function. What is the best way to resolve this?

Adding this will help at this stage?

```
ALTER PARTITION SCHEME [ps_tbl] NEXT USED 'FG_202002';
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION [pf_tbl]() SPLIT RANGE (N'2020-02-29T00:00:00.000');
```

Comment: AFAIK, there is no error message "partition range other than one day is not supported" that may be returned by SQL Server. Where are you getting that message?

Comment: The message is coming from SSIS job which runs this SP from execute SQL task.

Comment: Add the stored procedure code to your question.

Comment: It worked for me after adding above date range for 2-29-2020 but the surprise is, why it did not went to the right range which is 2020-03-01?  anyway Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you've got a [DDL trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15) with a leap-year bug. That is not a SQL Server system error message, and there's no built-in way to constrain the granularity of a partition function.

To check run:

```
select name, OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) trigger_body
from sys.triggers 
where parent_class = 0
```

DDL Triggers are often implemented without extensive testing, leap years commonly expose latent bugs.

Comment: Thanks but I dont have any trigger issues.

Comment: Then what's the full error message from SQL Server?

Comment: I have posted error message in question already David. Thaks and also It worked for me after adding above date range for 2-29-2020 but the surprise is, why it did not went to the right range which is 2020-03-01? anyway Thanks a lot

Comment: A SQL Server error message has message number, level, and state. eg `Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Divide by zero error encountered.`  What are those?  What's the definition of the partition function?